# How to bind graphicsmetrics jquery plugin in Angular app

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, metricsgraphicsjs

I'm doing an Angular app and I recently found [Metrics Graphics](http://metricsgraphicsjs.org/). The problem is that I'm having a hard time trying to integrate it to my angular app, given that is build for Jquery.

The another tricky problem is that my Angular app is consuming a restful API, and for the graphics that I want to integrate, the data is in the API.

The code to generate the graphics:

```
$(function () {
  d3.json('file/json.json', function(data) {
    data_graphic({
      data: data,
      width: 650,
      height: 150,
      target: '#element',
      x_accessor: 'Month',
      y_accessor: 'Value'
    })
  });
});
```

As you see, this code extracts data from a json file. Gratefully, my API is also returning json format in, i.e., http://api.example.com/api/data.

So what I want to do is bind this jquery script inside an angular directive (or controller) and make the data comes from the API and not a file.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example where everything is handled by a directive:

```
app.directive('metrics', function($http) {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element) {

      var success = function(result) {
        data_graphic({
          title: "UFO Sightings",
          description: "Yearly UFO sightings from 1945 to 2010.",
          data: result,
          markers: [{
            'year': 1964,
            'label': '"The Creeping Terror" released'
          }],
          width: 400,
          height: 250,
          target: element[0],
          x_accessor: "year",
          y_accessor: "sightings",
          interpolate: "monotone"
        });
      };

      var error = function() {
        console.log('Error.');
      };

      $http.get('data.json').success(success).error(error);
    }
  };
});
```

Usage:

```
<metrics></metrics>
```

You can replace `data.json` with the URL you need as long as it returns the correct format. The success function will initiate `data_graphic` and set `data` to the result from the `$http.get` and target to the directive DOM element.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/SOfTS6KL0GJ7ynvyrBfn?p=preview

If you want a controller to handle the retrieving of the data:

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $http) {

  var success = function(result) {
    $scope.data = result;
  };

  var error = function() {
    console.log('Error.');
  };

  $http.get('data.json').success(success).error(error);
});
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('metrics', function($http) {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      data: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {

      data_graphic({
        title: "UFO Sightings",
        description: "Yearly UFO sightings from 1945 to 2010.",
        data: scope.data,
        markers: [{
          'year': 1964,
          'label': '"The Creeping Terror" released'
        }],
        width: 400,
        height: 250,
        target: element[0],
        x_accessor: "year",
        y_accessor: "sightings",
        interpolate: "monotone"
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Usage:

```
<body ng-controller="MyController">
  <metrics ng-if="data" data="data"></metrics>
</body>
```

Note that `ng-if` is used to prevent the directive from executing before the data is available.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/96IVbjlZk8nriiREHdl4?p=preview

The next step would be to pass the entire object that is used in `data_graphic` to the directive as well, making it even more general and reusable.

Comment: Perfect! But when integrate it as a directive, requesting a GET to my API it doesn't load the graphics, and it gives me this error: `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLUnknownElement] svg .main-line` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure. Does it work when the controller makes the request?